# Jquery script not running inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script is running if i dont put it into a function but doesnt work inside function..

Please explain the logic to me

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var active=$('.active');
       var index=$('#pics li').index(active);
       var maxindex=$('#pics li').length-1;

       function makeCircles(){
           for (var i=0;i<=maxindex;i++)
           {
               var $circle=$("<li>",{class:'circle'});
               $('#navCircles').append($circle);
           }
        }   
      });
```

The code in makeCircles function is not running.
however it works fine if i remove the function and place those lines directly below variables... as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var active=$('.active');
var index=$('#pics li').index(active);
var maxindex=$('#pics li').length-1;

    for (var i=0;i<=maxindex;i++)
    {
        var $circle=$("<li>",{class:'circle'});
        $('#navCircles').append($circle);
    }   
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us how the "non functioning code" looks like? jsFiddle perhaps?

Comment: the function `makeCircles` is not invoked anywhere

Comment: you need to execute a function to execute the code inside so add: `makeCircles()`

Comment: Maybe because you're not invoking the function?

Comment: you have not invoked the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only defined the function, you also need to execute it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var active=$('.active');
   var index=$('#pics li').index(active);
   var maxindex=$('#pics li').length-1;

   function makeCircles(){ //define the function
       for (var i=0;i<=maxindex;i++)
       {
           var $circle=$("<li>",{class:'circle'});
           $('#navCircles').append($circle);
       }
    }   
    makeCircles(); //execute the function
  });
```

Comment: ohh!! thanks a lot! i just got confused and forgot to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to invoke the function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var active=$('.active');
   var index=$('#pics li').index(active);
   var maxindex=$('#pics li').length-1;

   (function makeCircles(){
       for (var i=0;i<=maxindex;i++)
       {
           var $circle=$("<li>",{class:'circle'});
           $('#navCircles').append($circle);
       }
    })();   
  });
```

Comment: why is invoking necessary? and is this () the you invoke function...just asking.

Comment: Because what you have done is just declared it. The code will only be executed when you call that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var active=$('.active');
   var index=$('#pics li').index(active);
   var maxindex=$('#pics li').length-1;

   function makeCircles(){ 
       for (var i=0;i<=maxindex;i++)
       {
           var $circle=$("<li>",{class:'circle'});
           $('#navCircles').append($circle);
       }
    }   
    makeCircles(); // call this function
});
```

Please try this.